# How to overload operators and not to use both "Curiously Recurring Template Pattern" and "Run Time polymorphism"

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, operator-overloading

1. I simply want to `overload + and = operators` in a **"Number"** class.
2. I want to have two child class **A. Integer B. Fraction**, which implements `"Number" class`. Currently below is how my code looks like. But here I am using `both Static and Run time polymorphism paradigm`. How to avoid it?

Code Snippet:

Number class:

```
template<class T>

class Number
{
    virtual T& operator= (const T &) = 0;      
    virtual const T operator+ (const T &) = 0;
    virtual void display(std::ostream &) = 0;
};
```

Integer Class:

```
// operator "=" overloading 
Integer& Integer::operator=(const Integer &secondNumber)
{
    intValue = secondNumber.intValue;
    return *this;
}

// operator "+" overloading
const Integer Integer::operator+(const Integer &secondNumber) 
{
     Integer temp;
     temp.intValue = this->intValue + secondNumber.intValue;
     return temp;
}
```

Also, if I remove "template" from my "Number" class I cannot overload + operator as it returns class instance, and we cannot have an instance of abstract class which is "Number class"

Also, if I cannot take virtual keyword out, as I want my child to implement the methods present in "Number class".

Kindly guide me a little here on is there any way to not have both type of Paradigm in code i.e, static and dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide which method you would prefer, and maybe also why you only want to use the one. However I do not see compile time polymorphism in your code, You are simply creating multiple instantiations of a generic template. The two instantiations have nothing in common, unless they too inherit a common interface.

And with regards to deciding which method to use, rather than looking at what you aim to get out of the code, what I have found is: you need to decide what features you do not need, or might not want included in your design.

Here is a very limited list of points, these may be good or bad depending on your situation:

#### Compile time polymorphism.

- Efficient; no virtual calls required, code can be optimized very well by compiler.
- Very strict (no base defined virtual functions): no derived implementation, boom, no compile.
- The base object (from a dynamic perspective) is not common, but unique to the template instantiation.
- Mixing lots of instantiations can create a large overhead (you could also abstract your design further to mitigate this).

#### Dynamic polymorphism.

- Unique *(derived)* types contain a common interface.
- As soon as you use a base pointer or reference, you can loose some optimizations (compile-time method can inline everything that is well defined and available in the current source, if it wants to).
- Unless a virtual function is pure: no implementation, no worries, no error (compile time, you'll have to discover a run-time error).

I can assume by your `Number` class you do not need an array of mixed types (`Number<int>` & `Number<float>`). If this is the case, a compile time solution may be suitable. However if you want to create a function which can operate on any form of `Number` then you'll have to either remove the template from `Number` or implement the function as a template also (may end up with code duplication for every `T`).

**U**pdate your question with more specific needs and the correct method, or combination, will be more apparent. I'll update this answer also.

Most of my points come from working with embedded systems. Consideration of the system capabilities is needed to make a well defined decision. Making code very abstract and confusing to the naked eye may not be worth it if you can plunder resources with little effect on the users experience.